# Shutter preferences are not getting saved

Tags: shutter

I have installed shutter package.And in preferences i have set save path to Desktop.When ever i close shutter and start again the save path points to somewherelse.It keeps changing randomly.I can't even figure out the problem.Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might be this issue -- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/shutter/+bug/657585

Comment: Is there any fix for the bug?

Comment: It's marked as "Fix Commited" and Shutter 0.87 will include this fix, but I couldn't find any fix or patch to apply...